# How do I load a webpage into an iframe on Firefox?

Tags: html, http

```
<head>
<style>
    iframe#hiddenframe {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="" id="hiddenframe"></iframe>
<img src="portait.jpg">
<a href="/?action=launch_rocket" target="hiddenframe"> Launch! </a>
</body>
```

So when I click the link, the rocket launches, but I stay on the page, keeping my eyes on the portrait. At least this is how it works on Chrome. Firefox still displays the blank page I loaded with "/?action=launch_rocket". I do not want to see the blank page. I want to keep looking at the portrait.
Our facility enforces using Firefox. Is there a smarter way of achieving what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the name of the iframe.

...

```
<iframe src="" id="hiddenframe" name="hiddenframe"></iframe>
```

...